# CSS not working on Chrome but works on Firefox and IE

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

http://foodstylingmentor.com

This is a WordPress website. You can see the child menu item under the ABOUT ME menu item. Firefox and IE are following the CSS but Chrome don't follow. I have cleared cache and history on all browsers.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    .main-navigation li ul li a:hover {
    background: #efefef !important;
    color: #7b0309 !important;
    }    
}
```

I also tried removing the @media etc. But still not working.

I already searched and tried to find solutions. But failed. So if anybody can help me, please do so.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: A few screenshots would help too. Don't expect the people here to have 3 browsers installed, and even if they do: the less effort we have to do, the greater the chance you get a quick and good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have the background set as `background: #efefef;`

In the `.main-navigation li ul li a` class add:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f7eabf, #936d28, #f7eabf, #000000);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

and the text should display like the parent text. Adding the above will cause a grey(ish) colour to appear because of this:

```
.main-navigation li ul li a:hover 
{
    background: #efefef !important;
    color: #7b0309 !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't give the same effect like in the Firefox.